# Why were these pasukim chosen for the upside down Nuns?

Tags: sin, hefsek-interruption, behaalotcha-parsha

In Bamidbar 10:35-36 there are two upside down Nuns. The traditional explanation is that this serves as a break between different accounts of wicked behavior. Not wanting to list three such counts in a row the torah inserts these bracketed verses:

> וַיְהִי בִּנְסֹעַ הָאָרֹן, וַיֹּאמֶר מֹשֶׁה:  קוּמָה ה', וְיָפֻצוּ אֹיְבֶיךָ, וְיָנֻסוּ מְשַׂנְאֶיךָ, מִפָּנֶיךָ.
>   וּבְנֻחֹה, יֹאמַר:  שׁוּבָה ה', רִבְבוֹת אַלְפֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל.

Why were these pesukim chosen to be the interrupting verses? And why 2?

Comment: That is only one traditional explanation.  See http://www.aish.com/tp/i/moha/48924777.html for another.

Comment: Note there are seven other upside down Nuns in Tanach as well.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33019&st=&pgnum=43&hilite= there is an explanation here to your question, however I do not have time to summarize. Perhaps someone will summarize and post as an answer.